The email is not being extracted from the googleIdToken
We obtain a Google ID token from Android using the code below:
BeginSignInRequest.Builder()
    .setGoogleIdTokenRequestOptions(
        BeginSignInRequest.GoogleIdTokenRequestOptions.builder()
            .setSupported(true)
            .setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(false)
            .setServerClientId(BuildConfig.GOOGLE_WEB_CLIENT_ID)
            .build(),
    )
    .setAutoSelectEnabled(true)
    .build()

and send it to the server
On the server side, we verify the token using the code below:
val verifier = GoogleIdTokenVerifier.Builder(GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(), GsonFactory())
.setAudience(listOf(clientId))
.build()

val verifiedIdToken = verifier.verify(idToken) ?: return

val email = verifiedIdToken.payload.email

Previously, this used to return the email, but now it's not showing up and only returns the following results
{
"aud":"....",
"azp":"....",
"exp":0000,
"iat":0000,
"iss":"....",
"sub":"....",
"picture":"...."
}

How can I extract the email from this token?

What is the type of the idToken object that is passed to the verify() function? I mean here, verifier.verify(idToken). Can you please show us how you got it?

@AlexMamo
Here is my code. Is there anything wrong with it?
val verifiedIdToken: com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleIdToken
= verifier.verify(idToken)

If you revoke access for that user (say, through "myaccounts.google.com" or calling the deprecated GoogleSignInClient#revokeAccess() (https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInClient#public-taskvoid-revokeaccess), does the problem go away? If you do it through  myaccounts site, you may need to wait a bit for that to clear the local cache. Alternatively, just create a new account and test with that and let us know please.
